# How can I pass more than one property to a Flink executable `FLINK_PROPERTIES` environment variable?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The [Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/) states that the `FLINK_PROPERTIES` environment variable can be used to pass configuration to a variety of Flink executables. For example `FLINK_PROPERTIES=jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager`.

How can I pass more that one configuration parameter? For example if I wanted to set `job manager.rpc.address` *and* `job manager.rpc.port` the following new line (`\n`) delimiter does not work.

`FLINK_PROPERTIES=\njobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\njob manager.rpc.port: 5600\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in shell then use that variable in the context you require:

```
> FLINK_PROPERTIES=$'\njobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\njobmanager.rpc.port\n'
> docker run --env "FLINK_PROPERTIES=$FLINK_PROPERTIES" ...
```

Note the use of single and double quotes.

It would be good to do it on one line though.